# how to clone a physical "individual partition" vmdk into a "local" (file-based) vmdk?

Tags: vmware-esx

I have a physical disk with a small (60GB) partition containing my guest OS. The physical disk also contains a large (240GB) block of unpartitioned space. My vmdk is defined as a physical "individual partition".

I want to convert the source physical "individual partition" vmdk into a local (file-based) vmdk. The command -

```
     vmware-vdiskmanager -r sourcevmdk targetvmdk -t 2
```

creates a 300GB vmdk that includes both the desired 60GB "individual partition" and the 240GB of useless unpartitioned space !

How can I create a local vmdk with just the individual partition?

Answer (score 3):

[VMware Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/features.html) will allow you to convert the VM and exclude the unused partition during the conversion. The standalone version is free and as far as I'm aware supports VMware Server as a destination platform - I'm assuming that's what you need as you are using vmware-vdiskmanager.

If you were using ESX\ESXi there are a number of command line alternatives but even so Converter is probably the simplest way to do this. Just make a copy of the whole VM, leaving out the unwanted partition, and delete the original (once you are certain the new VM is OK that is).